# Laravel 5.4 Ajax large file upload error and MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251

Tags: ajax, laravel, file, upload

im getting this error for files greater than 1mb. I can upload files lesser than 1mb. Im using godaddy shared hosting.
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
1/1
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:
in RouteCollection.php line 251
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 238
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 176
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is size error you should increase following:

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files:
`upload_max_filesize = 40M`

Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize:
`post_max_size = 40M`

Also check your ajax method (get/post/..) and correct it to be the same as in routes.php.